# Get process exit code in ipython (and other "special" environment variables)

Tags: python, unix, environment-variables, ipython, exit-code

Unix processes return a exit code, indicating if the process succeeded. In the shell this is represented with `$?`:

```
$ echo $?
0
```

This is called a [special variable](https://tecadmin.net/tutorial/bash-scripting/bash-command-arguments/) or a [shell parameter](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-parameters.html).

**How do you access shell special variables in the `ipython` shell?**

Things I tried and don't work:

- Using the [`%env` magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=%25var#magic-env). The variable is not listed there

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found:

```
In [22]: out = !false ; echo $?                                         

In [23]: code = int(out[-1])
```

It's ugly and error-prone. I hope there's a  better way